# Polly RetryForever isn't retrying

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic, exponential-backoff

I'm, trying to check a simple `RetryForever` of [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
           
        int i = 0;
        var _retryPolicy = Policy
       .Handle<Exception>()
       .RetryForever();

        _retryPolicy.Execute(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            i++;
            int.Parse("something");
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

A you can see I've created a variable `i` to track the number of the executions

**Excepted Result:**
print `i` = 0, 1, 2 etc

**Actual Result:**
print i = 0

Comment: Why is the Lamda marked "async"? There is nothing async about it.

Comment: Right! I remove it and it's working! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked your code and you had right, its stops on 0.

But when i removed async keyword (u didnt have any async operation here) the code runs correct.

So, try this:

```
using Polly;

int i = 0;
var _retryPolicy = Policy
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .RetryForever();

_retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
  i++;
  int.Parse("something");
  return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be late to the party but let me share my wisdom.

---

When you define a policy then you have to know **upfront** that you want to decorate a *sync* or an *async* method/function.

#### Retry policy for sync method

```
Policy
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .RetryForever();
```

#### Retry policy for async method

```
Policy
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .RetryForeverAsync();
```

- In the former case you have an `Execute` method which could anticipate

  - an `Action` (a method without return value)
  - or a `Func<TResult>` (a method with `TResult` typed return value)
  - and there are a dozen of other overloads
- In the latter case you have an `ExecuteAsync` method which could anticipate

  - a `Func<Task>` (an async method without return value)
  - or a `Func<Task<TResult>>` (an async method with `TResult` typed return value)
  - and there are a dozen of other overloads

#### Retry policy for sync function

```
Policy<int>
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .RetryForever();
```

#### Retry policy for async function

```
Policy<int>
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .RetryForeverAsync();
```

In these cases your to be decorated code should return an `int`.

So the `Execute` anticipates a `Func<int>` delegate

```
policy.Execute(() => { ... return 42; });
```

and the `ExecuteAsync` anticipates a `Func<Task<int>>` delegate

```
await policy.Execute(async () => { ... return Task.FromResult(42); });
```

---

Back to your code

Since you did not made any constraint on the return type during the policy definition that's why you could pass a `Func` which returns a `Task` (`Execute(async () => { ...});`).

So, your `Execute` returns a `Task` which is not `await`ed.

#### Let's await it

```
await _retryPolicy.Execute(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
    int.Parse("something");
});
```

If you `await` the returned `Task` then it will throw a `FormatException`.
But that Exception is thrown by the `await` which is outside of the `Execute`'s delegate. So, it will **NOT** trigger a retry.

#### Option A for fix

```
_retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
    int.Parse("something");
});
```

By removing `async`, your delegate will be an `Action` which will throw the `FormatException` which could trigger the retry policy.

#### Option B for fix

```
var _retryPolicy = Policy<int>
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .RetryForeverAsync();

await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
    int.Parse("something");
});
```

If you define your policy for async method and you `await` the `ExecuteAsync` then it will work as well. Why? Because [`ExecuteAsync` `await`s the provided delegate](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetryEngine.cs#L37) even if you did not define the delegate as `async`

```
await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
    int.Parse("something");
    return Task.CompletedTask; //This code is never reached
});
```